# Meteor.js - Can I do an HTTP POST to my Meteor app?

Tags: http, meteor

I have another app that runs on another server and occasionally this app runs a task asynchronously.  When this job completes, I would like to send some data to my Meteor app which my Meteor code will then munge and store in Mongo.  Is this possible?

Comment: Very possible, you can setup a REST API using `iron:router` server-side restful routes : http://eventedmind.github.io/iron-router/#restful-routes You will then be able to make HTTP POST and GET requests on your meteor app endpoints and handle the communication from another meteor app exactly like any other REST service. (This guide if for `iron:router@1.0.0-pre2`, this is worth noting).

Answer (score 1):

In combination to the comment by saimeunt, you can use Meteor's official HTTP functions: http://docs.meteor.com/#http_post

Comment: I thought those functions were for performing HTTP requests, not receiving them.